# How can I set/reset/change the stream top item id in Redis?

Tags: redis

While I was doing some testing in a Redis stream, I added a value into it with a high ID.

`XADD mystream 9999999999999999-1 field value`

Now I've found that this is the stream's top item, and trying to add anything with an automatic ID gets me
`9999999999999999-2`

Trying to add a stream with any ID lower than this results in an error:

`(error) ERR The ID specified in XADD is equal or smaller than the target stream top item`

I can just reset the stream back to my previous save of it, though I'm curious if there's any way to undo this action otherwise or reset the stream top item ID.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I subsequently found you can delete the stream, which allows you to start again,,, not sure if that helps...